# Use ros-indigo-opencv3 alongside 2.4.8?

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it is brand new but I've recently noticed I can install ros-indigo-opencv3.  It installs into the /opt/ros/indigo.  There is also a opencv 2.4.8 already installed into the system outside of /opt in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/, and every ros package from the repositories linked against opencv is linked to that.

When I try to build a package that depends on cv_bridge it fails:

```
CMakeFiles/rotate_cam.dir/src/rotate_cam.cpp.o: In function `RotateImage::RotateImage()':
rotate_cam.cpp:(.text+0x6dc): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
CMakeFiles/rotate_cam.dir/src/rotate_cam.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
rotate_cam.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/rotate_cam.dir/src/rotate_cam.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::String(std::string const&)':
rotate_cam.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2ERKSs[_ZN2cv6StringC5ERKSs]+0x69): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
```

And if I remove ros-indigo-opencv3 it builds fine.  With VERBOSE=1 I don't see any trace of opencv3 includes or libraries (cv_bridge properly brings in 2.4.8 libraries, and includes /usr/include/opencv which is still 2.4.8).

The problem is that it is using opencv 3.0 headers and linking against 2.4.8, and breakage between those produces the link error.

When the a node dependent on opencv 2.4.8 builds it runs:

`c++ ... -I/opt/ros/jade/include -I/usr/include/opencv ...`

It seem like one problem is that opencv 3.0 is installed in the jade directories and 2.4.8 is in the usr directory- so it is using the wrong header files.  But even when I correct this ordering the linker error still occurs.

What I'd like is to have opencv 3.0 available for special packages that need it (though they can't also link to cv_bridge, no mixing of 2.4.8 and 3.0 in the same package?).

I'm going to try to duplicate this problem on a small scale, it is possibly an artifact of something in one of my cmake files in my large workspace.

Ubuntu 14.04.2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214043/use-ros-indigo-opencv3-alongside-2.4.8?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2015-07-18

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2015-09-28**:
Any update on this? I working on a project with similar concerns.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-11-30**:
Tried this with ros-jade-opencv3.0 and it fails the same way.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-11-30**:
See https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/79

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-11-30**:
@jeremya I was able to get opencv 3.0 installed from source to a non-standard location and have a specific package find_package it.  ros-indigo-opencv3 seems just plain broken.  http://answers.ros.org/question/213925/opencv30-ros-indigo/?answer=213928#post-id-213928

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My current solution is to build OpenCV 3.0 from source and then install it into a location that is not on any paths.  Then in the package

```
# don't use opencv as found by any prior running of find_package
unset(OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH CACHE)
unset(OpenCV_DIR CACHE)

set(TMP_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "$ENV{HOME}/special/install")
find_package(OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED)

# restore CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and other cached variables
# so nothing other package finds this opencv
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${TMP_PREFIX_PATH})

unset(OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH CACHE)
unset(OpenCV_DIR CACHE)

...

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(foo_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2015-12-31**:
With this solution do you still have the limitation that you can't use `cv_bridge` in the same node?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-19**:
It does have that limitation- I haven't done it but cv_bridge could maybe be recompiled against cv 3.0 in the workspace.

**Comment by [cyberguy42](https://answers.ros.org/users/5314/cyberguy42/) on 2016-02-23**:
I spent hours trying to do this before finding this answer!
I can confirm that cv_bridge can be used in the same node: recompile cv_bridge from source and use this approach for both your code and cv_bridge.

**Comment by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on 2016-07-27**:
@Cyberguy42 did you do something special to compile from source, because dpkg did not help me.

**Comment by [cyberguy42](https://answers.ros.org/users/5314/cyberguy42/) on 2016-07-28**:
I didn't use dpkg at all; I downloaded this package [link text](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv) to my catkin workspace, applied the suggested changes to each affected CMakeLists, and compiled.

**Comment by [cyberguy42](https://answers.ros.org/users/5314/cyberguy42/) on 2016-07-28**:
However, I did encounter issues making my program into a nodelet: it compiled fine, but crashed at run time. Debugging revealed that it was trying to call the 2.4.8 library. Static compiling of 3.0 into my program didn't fix the problem. Lesson: run 2.4.8 and 3.0 code in separate processes.